# Handling void return in template function wrapper

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function wrapper for logging and timing purposes; following along with [this example](http://vitiy.info/c11-functional-decomposition-easy-way-to-do-aop/), I have a pretty good handle on how to do that so far:

```
template <typename R, typename ...Args>
std::function<R(Args...)> logged(string name, std::function<R(Args...)> f)
{
    return [f,name](Args... args){

        LOG << name << " start" << NL;
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        R result = f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto total = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count();
        LOG << "Elapsed: " << total << "us" << NL;

        return result;
    };
}
```

However, this only works for functions with a non-void return type.  While I could easily write a copy that replaces all instances of "R" with a void (i.e. takes and returns `std::function<void(Args...)> f`), I'd prefer to avoid duplicating if possible.  Is there a way I can handle cases where `R` is void?

I've attempted to use type_traits::is_void and branching logic to handle the problem, but I would always get the error `missing template arguments before ( token if(!is_void(R)::value)`.

I should mention, due to workplace constraints, I'm working with C++11.

Comment: It should be `std::is_void<R>::value` or `std::is_void_v<R>`. Also don't forget to use `if constexpr` instead of plain `if`.

Comment: [`is_void`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_void) is a templated type trait and expects a template argument. It's not a function that you call.

Comment: Note also that you don't handle correctly reference return type, you should add `-> R` to your lambda.

Comment: A `void()` function is allowed to `return` a `void` value.  It is the only value a `void()` function is allowed to `return`. In fact, it is because of templates that this is allowed, so that you don't have to treat `void` returns special. And if you wrap the logging in an RAII object, you can get rid of the `result` variable and just `return f(...);`, which is allowed for `void`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use RAII to use one unique function:

```
template <typename F>
struct Finally {
    Finally(F f) : f(f) {}
    ~Finally() { f(); }

    Finally(const Finally&) = delete;
    Finally& operator=(const Finally&) = delete;

    F f;
};

// pre C++17
template <typename F>
Finally<F> make_finally(F f) {
    return {f};
}


template <typename R, typename ...Args>
std::function<R(Args...)> logged(string name, std::function<R(Args...)> f)
{
    return [f, name](Args... args) -> R {
        LOG << name << " start" << NL;
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        Finally finally([&](){ // C++17
        // auto&& finally = make_finally([&](){ // Pre-C++17
            auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto total = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count();
            LOG << "Elapsed: " << total << "us" << NL;
        });
        return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
}
```

Comment: I implemented your C++ changes (I'm on C++11 due to workplace constraints, so I'm working with the pre-17 version).  It's running into an error because it's trying to call `Finally(const Finally& f)` constructor, which is deleted.

Comment: @BrandonMcKenzie: missing `&&` after `auto`, fixed.

Comment: That modification fixed it.  Thanks!